# I sold off my NVDA stock on June 21(record date) in after hours trade

Tags: stocks, trading, dividends, stock-split

I sold off my NVDA stock on june 21 after hours trade. I did not get any stock as dividend yet.
will I not get it ?

Comment: When did your trade settle?

Comment: Did you get the pre-split price for your shares or was the sale price 1/4 of the price before close? You either get the pre-dividend price or the dividend, but not both.

Comment: @BobBaerker: Because it's the dividend record date right there in your quote?  The payable date and ex-dividend date are in July but the record date was in June.

Comment: @quid - settled on june 23 as per the document I downloaded

Comment: @sunset144 please see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for help on combining your two accounts.

Answer (score 5):

> If you sell your stock before the ex-dividend date, you also are selling away your right to the stock dividend. **Your sale includes an obligation to deliver any shares acquired as a result of the dividend to the buyer of your shares**, since the seller will receive an I.O.U. or "due bill" from his or her broker for the additional shares. Thus, it is important to remember that the day you can sell your shares without being obligated to deliver the additional shares is not the first business day after the record date, but usually is the first business day after the stock dividend is paid.

from [Investor.gov](https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/investing-basics/glossary/ex-dividend-dates-when-are-you-entitled-stock-and)

Probably your broker has taken care of this for you, by accepting the dividend shares and delivering them to the buyer, fulfilling the above obligation.